# How to create a Discord bot that sends images froma Google Drive folder (Python)

Tags: python, discord, bots, drive

at the moment I have a fully functioning Discord bot in Python which can send pictures using pictures on the local system. However I want it to be able to send pictures from a Google Drive folder but I'm not sure if that is even possible. I have looked around on the internet and I have never found something which matches my question. I know there is a PyDrive API but I am also not sure whether that will do it.

Comment: You can download the images with [pydrive](https://googleworkspace.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/filemanagement.html#download-file-content) and then send them with the same code you wrote before

Comment: It looks like pydrive is blocking, which means that if you want to send a google drive file every time someone enters a command, it won't accept any other commands while downloading the file. If you don't want this to happen, you can make a helper function that runs in the background and add tasks to its queue every time you run the command.

Comment: @joscha the problem is though, I want to use repl.it to host the bot so that it can stay on 24/7 but the pictures are pictures of me and my friends and I don't want the host to have access to those pictures. That is why is was wondering if it even was possible

Comment: @LeeGarcon how fast would that be, would the server on which I host the bot have access to those pictures and how exactly would that be achieved?

Comment: @Athlon I'm not so familiar with repl.it (I used it a while ago but I don't know how it is right now) but I think you can save files in a repl instance. You can just access them as you would any other file. I'm also not very familiar with PyDrive, but that shouldn't be very difficult neither.